# How come when I render animation, Blender isn’t rendering frame by frame?

Tags: keyframes

When I hit the Render animation button, blender goes from camera angle, to a zoomed out (away from platform) angle and actually plays the animation. Instead of, doing the usual rendering —- with the brackets showing revealing each pixel and going frame by frame. It’s as if it’s rendering the screen and not the actual animation...

Comment: Double check you dont have animation on your camera and it is moving it out that far. If you can attach screen shots it would be easier to figure out

Comment: It sounds like you used OpenGL Render Animation instead of the regular animation render.